# jASEN in Java project to detect spam email

Tags: java, email, spam

I want to use [jASEN](http://www.jasen.org/) in my Java project, in order to retrieve the spam score for a set of emails I have.

My code is as follows:

```
public static double Get_jASEN_Score(MimeMessage mm) {
    double jASEN_score = -1;

    try {
        // Initialise the scanner
        JasenScanner.getInstance().init();

        JasenScanResult result = JasenScanner.getInstance().scan(mm);
        jASEN_score = result.getProbability();
    } catch (JasenException e) {
        Console.Console.Print_To_Console(String.format("jASEN Spam filter Error: %s", e.getMessage()), true, false);
    }

    return jASEN_score;
}
```

The problem is that the: `JasenScanner.getInstance().init();` line process time is everlasting. I placed the "jasen-conf" folder at the right place. 
Any suggest what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private static final JasenScanner JASEN_SCANNER = JasenConnection.getInstance();

public static double getJASENScore(MimeMessage message) {
    try {
        JasenScanResult result = JASEN_SCANNER.scan(message);
        return result.getProbability();
    } catch (JasenException ex) {
        LOGGER.info("JASON error; " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

edit:

```
public class JasenConnection {

private static JasenScanner jasenScanner;

protected JasenConnection() {
    try {
        JasenScanner.getInstance().init();
        ErrorHandlerBroker.getInstance().setErrorHandler(new EmptyErrorHandler());
        jasenScanner = JasenScanner.getInstance();
    } catch (JasenException ex) {
        //LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static JasenScanner getInstance() {
    if (null == jasenScanner) {
        new JasenConnection();
    }
    return jasenScanner;
}
```

}

Comment: JasenConnection Object is not exist or i can't find it.